# What makes a Maven plugin managed?

Tags: maven

I wasn't able to figure this one out through searching, and the local maven guy had never seen this either:

The idea is to add the maven-release-plugin to a project, for testing and experimenting before using it in our production application.

While adding the plugin (Eclipse > pom.xml > Add plugin), there's an indication that version 2.0 of this plugin is locked and "managed". I've attached a screenshot.

The question is simple: why is this? Can I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a managed dependency version is one that appears in an inherited POM's `<dependencyManagement>` section, or for plugins in a `<pluginManagement>` section:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Forgot that they have to be defined in one of the management sections instead of a normal dependency. This should be the right answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know a managed plugin as a plugin whos version is defined in a parent pom. You still add the dependency in your own pom but can omitt the version because it's pulled from the parent where the dependency is defined including the version.

I think it is possible to override the version in your pom but I'm not sure if the managed tag will disappear.